# Oracle regex for all characters after a specific character

Tags: oracle

I need to get all characters after the last 'R' from a part number like this:

223A GHH R337716

So far I've got:

```
 REGEXP_SUBSTR(CUST_PART_NO,'R(.*)')
```

This returns R337716, but I don't want the 'R' and I'm not sure if it would work if there was more than one 'R' in the string.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Then you have to replace the string with groups of expressions like this:

```
regexp_replace( CUST_PART_NO, '(.*)(R)(.*)', '\3' )
```

See it here on sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3ec77/2

What I'm saying with this expression is:

- get everything until `R` make it as a group 1 expression the first `(.*)`
- get the `R` make it the second group `(R)`
- get everything else and make it the third group `(.*)`

The parenthesis on a regular expression define groups of expressions.

Comment: Would this still work if there was more than one "R" ? I would need everything after the last "R"

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It will work exactly with the last `R` the `.*` mask means everithing until the last R

Comment: Yes, I tested it using the fiddle you posted. thanks for all the help, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
ltrim(REGEXP_SUBSTR(CUST_PART_NO,'R(.*)'), 'R')
```